# Matlab command window unresponsive after losing focus

Tags: matlab, gnome

I am using matlab on linux with gnome and I have a problem with the command window. Note that this problem goes away when I switch to twm, but I don't want to do that (for obvious reasons).

When the command window loses focus and then regains focus, it freezes, i.e., it ignores anything I type. The only consistent way I've found to unfreeze it is to click somewhere within the matlab window, but outside the command window (for example, the workspace or command history windows), and then click back in the command window.

This is very annoying and it happens all the time. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You may want to try asking this question on Super User stack exchange, this site is primarily for Coding problems rather than individual application errors.

Comment: This is not the place to ask your question. You might go to superuser as suggested, or contact technical support at The MathWorks. After all, this is a question they should answer, and they will give you the best answer.